# Why wasn't my javascript class visible inside the .cshtml file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a fresh .net-core project and then i added a bundleconfig.json file for bundling and minifying and i also added a package.json file for handling dependencies.

I included my bundle inside the shared _Layout.cshtml file but then i tried to initialize my class inside my Index.html file.

So at my _Layout.cshtml file i had these lines:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

site.min.js contains my class (Swiper).

In my Index.cshtml i had these lines:

```
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    });
</script>
```

At this point Swiper was undefined without an explicit include but it was present inside site.min.js. After i moved the content of this  tag into a javascript file that is also part of my site.min.js it started to finally work.

Is there any scope for the script tags that i was unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap them in a `Section` like this:

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    });
</script>
}
```

The name "Scripts" could be what ever you want as long as its the same in the layout.